# Using SQLCMD variables in a condition

Tags: c#, t-sql, visual-studio-2012, sqlcmd

When publishing a new database, I want to run a procedure only if the server has `SQL Agent` installed.

Therefor, I created a new `SQLCMD` variable called `$(SqlAgent)` and I want to add a condition (instead of checking if `SQLAgent` runs in `msdb.dbo.sysjobs` cause sometimes it is installed but doesn't run).

And I add the following

```
 IF $(SqlAgent)='exists'
 BEGIN
EXEC [INFRA]....

 END
```

This fails because of

> incorrect syntax next to SqlAgent

How can I use `sqlcmd` variable in a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check if you are running your script window as sqlcmd. The try this instead

```
IF ('$(SqlAgent)' = 'exists')
Begin
    Exec ...
End
```